# Android/Eclipse - Notepad v1 tutorial: No menu button

Tags: android

So - as far as I know, it was all fine. It compiled fine, no reported errors, but when it runs in the emulator, there is no menu button - no way to add notes.  It just has the default 'No notes yet' message.

When I compile the 'solution' it is exactly the same - no button.  In addition, in comparing the source code, as far as I can tell, it's just the same...  So - Mac OS 10.5.8, everything up to date, no obvious errors - perhaps it's me not knowing Android?

I just don't know?

Cheers

Comment: try pressing the menu button on the phone?

Comment: Without code, it is hard to tell what is wrong, edit in your code

Comment: Hit the physical menu button on the phone to bring up the menu on the app.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it is you not knowing Android. There is no onscreen menu button in most Android apps - have you tried pressing the hardware menu button at the bottom of your phone, or in the key panel of the emulator?

Comment: Am too stupid to own a computer.  That's exactly what it was.  Thank you for your patience in the face of idiocy...

Comment: Or maybe you're just not used to Android. My primary device is an iPhone, so when I switch to Android for development purposes, I find myself getting stumped on all kinds of simple things.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the hard way.

I Pressed the "Page Up" key on my keyboard to get the "Menu"